# Unsure about basic discrete math

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

[Question 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDiQT.png)

Seeing that set $B$ is a member of set $A$, and set $C$ is by extension a member of set $A$ by being a member of set $B$, I would like to think that both $B$ and $C$ are empty sets since their requirements are based on values that don't exist in set $A. (A = {7})$

It's also difficult to imagine that all most of these answers would simply be "$\{ \}$", so I am assuming that I don't understand this correctly.

Thanks,
CS

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... Note that $A$ isn't $\{7\}$ (with curly braces) but $[7]$ (with square braces). Double-check how your book uses that notation. Many authors take $[n]$ to mean $\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$ (or maybe also including $0$), but I don't know how universal this is.

Comment: Is there a reason that problem can't be typed into the question?

Comment: If $B \in A$ and $C \in B$, it may or may not be true that $C \in A$.  The sets $A$ for which that's always true are called "transitive" sets.  But there's an important difference between that situation and the situation $B \subseteq A$ and $C \in B$, which *does* always mean that $C \in A$.

Comment: Please note that when you use images to convey text, you make the site less accessible to a significant number of users.  Please read [this post], which explains the problems with using images instead of text.  For typing mathematics, please refer to the [MathJax guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/).